# Dart lang setting request header give Breaking on exception: Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

Tags: dart

I am trying to resolve how to set a request header in Dart in a HttpRequest

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
  req.open("Get", gotest);
  req.onLoadEnd.listen((event) => onSuccess(req));
  req.send(null);
```

results in:

```
Breaking on exception: Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
```

edit:
gotest is set to

```
  var gotest = "http://127.0.0.1:9900/janus/parameter/sampleCount/201/1225/1313";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation for `setRequestHeader`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#setRequestHeader) states:

> You must call `open()` before using this method.

Reorder those lines as this:

```java
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.open("Get", "www.google.com");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the Future based API. You won't have to mess with open(), send(), etc.

Try this:

```
HttpRequest.request('/foo',
    method: 'GET',
    requestHeaders: {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
  .then(onSuccess)
  .catchError(handleTheError);
```